# JS: Calculating values that have dot and comma (i.e 1.000,00)

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency-formatting

I have a script using jQuery which calculates currency. It works fine, but when  I write a value greater than `999,99`, it returns a value with error when I use a mask and convert the result to money format. How can I fix that?

**UPDATED**

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.money').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
});

accounting.settings = {
  currency: {
    symbol : "",   // default currency symbol is '$'
    format: "%s%v", // controls output: %s = symbol, %v = value/number (can be object: see below)
    decimal : ",",  // decimal point separator
    thousand: ".",  // thousands separator
    precision : 2   // decimal places
  },
  number: {
    precision : 0,  // default precision on numbers is 0
    thousand: ".",
    decimal : ","
  }
}


function calc(){
  var plano = parseFloat($("#regimento").val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
  var gasto = parseFloat($("#gasto_contabilidade").val().replace(/\./g, ',').replace(/,/g, '.'));
  var meses = parseInt( $("#meses").val());

  var resultado_gasto = parseFloat(gasto * meses);
  var resultado_plano = parseFloat(plano * meses);

  var result = resultado_gasto - resultado_plano;
  result = accounting.formatMoney(result);
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<script src="http://dubsolucoes.com.br/razonet/wp-content/themes/razonet_wp/assets/javascript/vendor/accounting.min.js"></script>



<select name="" id="regimento" class="select">
  <option value="19,90">MEI</option>
  <option value="85,90">SIMPLES SERVIÇO</option>
  <option value="199,90">SIMPLES COMÉRCIO E INDÚSTRIA</option>
</select>

<input id="gasto_contabilidade" type="text" class="money" value="100000">

<select id="meses" class="select">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate">
```

Comment: Could you provide the input values you are using for the different parameters?

Comment: Can you include the HTML of the elements that the code uses, like `#regimento` and others? And also, when you say "*...I write a value greater than 999,99...*", which value are you talking about?

Comment: 1. You are not using ‘meses’ variable 2. Replace only replaces single occurrence. 1,000,000 has 2 comma chars

Comment: use `parseDouble()` instead of `parseInt()` as it parse integer of limited range

Comment: Sure! Already done =D

Comment: It'd help if you gave an english translation of what these fields are supposed to represent. e.g. what is `gasto_contabilidade`? As it stands it's very hard to understand what your trying to achieve here

Comment: gasto_contabilidade = `accounting_expenses`. `meses` is `months`

Comment: Yes, thats it  =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX:

I solve the problem removing the dot before calculate it

```
var gasto = $("#gasto_contabilidade").val().replace(".", '');
```

Thanks by helping guys!

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.money').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
});

accounting.settings = {
  currency: {
    symbol : "",   // default currency symbol is '$'
    format: "%s%v", // controls output: %s = symbol, %v = value/number (can be object: see below)
    decimal : ",",  // decimal point separator
    thousand: ".",  // thousands separator
    precision : 2   // decimal places
  },
  number: {
    precision : 0,  // default precision on numbers is 0
    thousand: ".",
    decimal : ","
  }
}


function calc(){
  var gasto = $("#gasto_contabilidade").val().replace(".", ''); // FIX
  plano = parseFloat($("#regimento").val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
  gasto = parseFloat(gasto.replace(/\./g, ',').replace(/,/g, '.'));
  var meses = parseInt( $("#meses").val());

  var resultado_gasto = parseFloat(gasto * meses);
  var resultado_plano = parseFloat(plano * meses);

  var result = resultado_gasto - resultado_plano;
  result = accounting.formatMoney(result);
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<script src="http://dubsolucoes.com.br/razonet/wp-content/themes/razonet_wp/assets/javascript/vendor/accounting.min.js"></script>


<script>



</script>

<select name="" id="regimento" class="select">
  <option value="19,90">MEI</option>
  <option value="85,90">SIMPLES SERVIÇO</option>
  <option value="199,90">SIMPLES COMÉRCIO E INDÚSTRIA</option>
</select>

<input id="gasto_contabilidade" type="text" class="money" value="100000">

<select id="meses" class="select">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that when getting the `.val()` from a `select`, it comes as string, you should parse it before do some calculations.

Also, I don't know why you are using `input type="tel"` to use as number, use `type="number"`

Code below is working and not showing `NaN`... I just don't know if the results of the calculations are what you are looking for,

**OBS**: You can't use values in `#gasto_contabilidade` like `1.234,55`, it must be `1234.55` or `1234,55` (this one just because you are replace the `,`.

```js
function calc(){
  var plano = parseFloat($("#regimento").val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
  var gasto = parseFloat($("#gasto_contabilidade").val().replace(/\./g, ',').replace(/,/g, '.'));
  var meses = parseInt( $("#meses").val());

  var resultado_gasto = parseFloat(gasto * meses);
  var resultado_plano = parseFloat(plano * meses);

  var result = resultado_gasto - resultado_plano;
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="regimento" class="select">
  <option value="19,90">MEI</option>
  <option value="85,90">SIMPLES SERVIÇO</option>
  <option value="199,90">SIMPLES COMÉRCIO E INDÚSTRIA</option>
</select>

<input id="gasto_contabilidade" type="number" class="valor" value="1000">

<select id="meses" class="select">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate">
```

Comment: Great, thanks, but if I format the value with accounting.js it not work very well, take a look my answer below

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not using `meses` variable
2. When using`.replace` with string, it replaces only single occurrence. When using with regex it replaces all occurrences

   ```
    gasto.replace(/,/gi,'.').replace(/ /gi,'')
   ```

That way strings replaced properly

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks, but if I format the value with [accounting.js](https://github.com/openexchangerates/accounting.js/) it not work very well, look:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.money').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
});

accounting.settings = {
  currency: {
    symbol : "",   // default currency symbol is '$'
    format: "%s%v", // controls output: %s = symbol, %v = value/number (can be object: see below)
    decimal : ",",  // decimal point separator
    thousand: ".",  // thousands separator
    precision : 2   // decimal places
  },
  number: {
    precision : 0,  // default precision on numbers is 0
    thousand: ".",
    decimal : ","
  }
}


function calc(){
  var plano = parseFloat($("#regimento").val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
  var gasto = parseFloat($("#gasto_contabilidade").val().replace(/\./g, ',').replace(/,/g, '.'));
  var meses = parseInt( $("#meses").val());

  var resultado_gasto = parseFloat(gasto * meses);
  var resultado_plano = parseFloat(plano * meses);

  var result = resultado_gasto - resultado_plano;
  result = accounting.formatMoney(result);
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<script src="http://dubsolucoes.com.br/razonet/wp-content/themes/razonet_wp/assets/javascript/vendor/accounting.min.js"></script>


<script>



</script>

<select name="" id="regimento" class="select">
  <option value="19,90">MEI</option>
  <option value="85,90">SIMPLES SERVIÇO</option>
  <option value="199,90">SIMPLES COMÉRCIO E INDÚSTRIA</option>
</select>

<input id="gasto_contabilidade" type="text" class="money" value="100000">

<select id="meses" class="select">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate">
```